# Python3: Reportlab Image - ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=...>

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

When I run a unit test,  I'm getting Python 3 unclosed buffer error on the "logo" image in the following code. How do I close the logo image buffer correctly? Please be aware that the `Image` class is coming from `reportlab.platypus`.

I have tried `logo.close()` and `with Image(logo_path) as logo:`, both of them does not work.

```
>>python -m unittest tests.test_sample_pdf

>>/tests/test_sample_pdf.py:51: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name='/Users/my_prj/statics/my-logo.gif'>
      get_pdf()
```

Source Code

```
import unittest
import os
from io import BytesIO
from os.path import abspath, dirname
from reportlab.lib.colors import HexColor
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_RIGHT
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import inch, cm, mm
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, BaseDocTemplate, Paragraph, Image, Spacer


COL_SORT = [{"headerName": "name",
             "field": "name",
             "width": 1000,}]

def get_pdf():
    # setup PDF template
    buffer = BytesIO()
    side_margin = 12
    col_widths = [row['width'] for row in COL_SORT]
    page_width = sum(col_widths) + side_margin * 3
    pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=(page_width, 8.5 * inch), rightMargin=side_margin, leftMargin=side_margin,
                            topMargin=side_margin, bottomMargin=side_margin)
    elements = []

    # logo
    parent_dir = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
    logo_path = os.path.join(parent_dir, 'statics', 'my-logo.gif')
    logo = Image(logo_path)
    logo.hAlign = 'LEFT'

    heading_style = ParagraphStyle(name='heading', fontSize=16, leading=20, spaceAfter=0,
                                   textColor=HexColor('#ffffff'), backColor=HexColor('#465a81'))
    heading_right_style = ParagraphStyle(name='heading', fontSize=16, leading=20, spaceAfter=0,
                                         textColor=HexColor('#ffffff'), backColor=HexColor('#465a81'),
                                         alignment=TA_RIGHT)
    logo_tbl = Table([[logo]], colWidths=sum(col_widths))
    logo_tbl.hAlign = 'LEFT'
    logo_tbl.setStyle(TableStyle([('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, -1), HexColor('#B90002'))]))
    elements.append(logo_tbl)

    # build PDF
    pdf.build(elements)
    pdf_string = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()

class TestPDF(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_pdf(self):
        get_pdf()
```

Comment: `del logo` doesn't necessarily close the file.

Comment: Show full Traceback

Comment: I have shown the full Traceback and full source code.

Comment: There must be some more code you haven't shown us, because that stack error says it occurred on line 51, but what you've provided only has 49 lines. In particular, please post any code that has anything to do with that .gif file.

Comment: Just as another thought, you don't have that gif file open in any other programs, do you? Just making doubly sure cause checking takes only a second.

Comment: No, I don't have the image open in another program.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that `reportlab` expects that **you** open and close the image file. Use `with open(logo_path, 'rb') as image_fd:`.

This workaround solves the Warning. I've added the mentioned `with` and indented its following lines.

```
def get_pdf():
    # setup PDF template
    buffer = BytesIO()
    side_margin = 12
    col_widths = [row['width'] for row in COL_SORT]
    page_width = sum(col_widths) + side_margin * 3
    pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=(page_width, 8.5 * inch), rightMargin=side_margin, leftMargin=side_margin,
                            topMargin=side_margin, bottomMargin=side_margin)
    elements = []

    # logo
    parent_dir = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
    logo_path = os.path.join(parent_dir, 'statics', 'nci-logo.gif')
    with open(logo_path, 'rb') as image_fd:            # edited this line
        logo = Image(image_fd)                         # ... and this line
        logo.hAlign = 'LEFT'

        heading_style = ParagraphStyle(name='heading', fontSize=16, leading=20, spaceAfter=0,
                                   textColor=HexColor('#ffffff'), backColor=HexColor('#465a81'))
        heading_right_style = ParagraphStyle(name='heading', fontSize=16, leading=20, spaceAfter=0,
                                         textColor=HexColor('#ffffff'), backColor=HexColor('#465a81'),
                                         alignment=TA_RIGHT)
        logo_tbl = Table([[logo]], colWidths=sum(col_widths))
        logo_tbl.hAlign = 'LEFT'
        logo_tbl.setStyle(TableStyle([('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, -1), HexColor('#B90002'))]))
        elements.append(logo_tbl)

        # build PDF
        pdf.build(elements)
        pdf_string = buffer.getvalue()
        buffer.close()
```

Output:

```
$ python -m unittest tests.test_sample_pdf
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.042s

OK
```

I've put the complete example in [Github](https://github.com/xbx/reportlab-example)